# creating multiple foreign keys Django

Tags: python, django, models

I am trying to create a database where you have 3 columns. Column A, Column B, Column C. Column B selection is based on the selection of Column A and Column C is based on both column B & A. I wasn't able to find information on multiple foreignKey instances.

```
class Color(models.Model):
"""A color that can be entered for a drop down list"""
part = models.ForeignKey('Part', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
text = models.TextField()
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Color is tied to 'Part' but I also want 'Part' to be connected to a class called 'Program'

So I want to associate a color with a certain part which is associated with a certain program. Hope this makes sense any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate model known as Program e.g:

```
class Program(models.Model):
  .........
```

Now in your Part model add a foreign key to Program model

```
class Part(models.Model):
  program = models.ForeignKey('Program',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now your Color model already has a foreign key to the Part model.Now fetch a Part for a particular Program, then fetch a Color for that particular part.